# Typescript/Javascript assign and return one-liner

Tags: javascript, typescript

Many times I ask myself the same question... With all that syntaxes (not always intuitive) to write quite direct code in JS, I was wondering, would someone know about a one-liner for that kind of operation?

```
var setFeatured = entry => { 
  entry.isFeatured = true;
  return entry
}

SomeCallThatReturnsAPromise.then(entries => entries.map(setFeatured))
```

To assign a property and return the object in one shot, that I could put in a readable way directly as arg of `entries.map`

---

To give a feedback about what was proposed to me, the common answer was to return a result with a OR operator, after an assignation or function call (which returns `undefined`, `null`, `false`, `never`, well anything that will trigger the part after the OR):

`return entry.isFeatured = true || entry`

The interest of my question was to know if I could take advantage of a more compact syntax:

```
SomeCallThatReturnsAPromise()
    .then((entries:EntryType[]) => entries
         .map(entry => entry.isFeatured = true || entry)
         .filter(entry => entry.something == true))
    .then((entries:EntryType[]) => someCallThatReturnsNothingButHasToBeDoneThere() || entries)
    .then((entries:EntryType[]) => console.log(entries))
```

would be easier to read than:

```
SomeCallThatReturnsAPromise
    .then((entries:EntryType[]) => entries
         .map(entry => {
            entry.isFeatured = true;
            return entry;
         })
         .filter(entry => entry.something == true))                              
    .then((entries:EntryType[]) => {
            someCallThatReturnsNothingButHasToBeDoneThere();
            return entries;
        })
    .then((entries:EntryType[]) => console.log(entries))
```

Notes:

1) I try to avoid creating a function for that. My question was motivated by curiosity and just concerns what Vanilla ES6 or 7 syntaxes have to offer.

2) I was answered to use `.forEach` rather than `.map`. I design my code with a functional approach (hence the importance of compact callbacks), so `.forEach`is not necessarily a good choice for me (and apparently it doesn't have advantages over map in terms of performance or memory consumption). A one-line syntax is convenient both when handling promises callbacks or chains of array functions...

3) the returned type when using the OR operator is a union type, `EntryType|null`. So it breaks the typing for the subsequent calls and implies a type assertion:

```
SomeCallThatReturnsAPromise()
    .then((entries:EntryType[]) => entries
         .map(entry => (entry.isFeatured = true || entry) as EntryType)
         .filter(entry => entry.something == true))
    .then((entries:EntryType[]) => (someCallThatReturnsNothingButHasToBeDoneThere() || entries) as EntryType[])
    .then((entries:EntryType[]) => console.log(entries))
```

That's getting heavier... I still don't know if I'll use that or stick with the two lines including the return statement.

4) That's a reduced example. I know that my first `then` contains a synchronous call or that my example could be more accurate.

Comment: Using `map` makes no sense if you return the exact same items.

Comment: Oh. see my answer to how you can use `forEach` and then return `entries`

Comment: Yes but it's not a one-liner anymore :)

Comment: That's the point. As [described in MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators): "**expr1 || expr2** Returns expr1 if it can be converted to true; otherwise, returns expr2". As `forEach` returns `void` it will automatically return `entries`.

Comment: My answer seems to have only one line, hence it's a "one-liner", no?

Comment: And for the context, I'm not trying to solve something crucial, just asking a simple "can we do that in JS"? With those syntaxes such as "stuff || default" or "!!val", I'm wondering if there's something I haven't seen yet for that particular case.

Comment: @nitzan Yep, true, I was mistaking with Sirko's `forEach` answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
//Example 1
const gimmeSmile = {}

console.log({ ...gimmeSmile, smile: ":)" })

// Example 2
const smiles = [{},{},{}]
  .map(obj => ( { ...obj, smile: ":)"} ));

console.log(smiles)
```

Comment: consider adding more explanation to the answer to help us understand more instead of just posting a block of code

Comment: Indeed, with the spread/rest operators everything has become easier, and my question is not actual anymore.

Answer (score 7):

```
entries.forEach( (entry) => entry.isFeatured = true );
```

No need to define the function separately.

Furthermore, as your elements are objects and are handled by reference, one can replace `map()` by `forEach()`, which removes the necessity to return a value.
(using `map()` you would end up with two arrays consisting of the same elements, which probably is not, what you need)

Comment: About the forEach, my call is following a promise (edited my post), so I have to return something. Foreach would make me use another return, not a one-liner anymore. Except if I miss something?

Comment: For this see the other answers below, but I think, that at some point here the readability of your code is too low, so I'd rather recommend adding a few lines of code to save the next developer a few minutes in understanding the code.

Answer (score 4):

You can do what @Sirko wrote but return it like so:

```
SomeCallThatReturnsAPromise.then(entries => entries.forEach(entry => entry.isFeatured = true) || entries)
```

There's no need to use `map`, instead using `forEach` will give you a "one-liner", but then you want to return the same value that you received, using logical or (`||`) you can do that.

Comment: While I'm at it, it's still a readable syntax, maybe I'll adopt that (at least it's way more readable than some sections of TS doc about generics)

Answer (score 2):

although @Sirko is right and, in that specific case, `forEach` has more sense than using `map` I think the OP was asking a generic question.

So, in general, how do you assign a property and then return the whole object? this is my suggestion:

```js
function mutateObject(element, value) {
 return (element.prop = value) && element || element
}

var object = {prop:1}
var returned = mutateObject(object, 2)

console.log(returned)
```

How does it work? the first part `(element.prop = value)` assigns the `value` to the property and return the `value` to the expression.

If the value returned is falsy, the value of the `||` clause is returned. If it's truthy the value of the `&&` is returned.

In this case we return the `element` itself both times to be sure that's the object it will always be returned, no matter what we set in the property.

Another way to write that is `(element.prop = value) ? element : element` but, with this syntax, it looks more like a typo with the assignment instead of the comparison so I like the other syntax better.

Comment: The syntax you propose is about the same as Nitzan (to use AND/OR operators to return the result). He answered just before you... Sorry that I can't give two checks.